# Find tangent line satisfying certain requirements to curve equation with optimizer?

Tags: python, optimization, curve, derivative

I have what seems to be a relatively simplistic geometric optimization question, but one in which I have absolutely no experience.

I have a bunch of data that I am fitting a spline through to find its equation, such as the below,

[image]

And this is the equation I fit to the dots,

[image]

with the code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

plt.figure(figsize=(6.5, 4))
plt.axis([0.017,.045,.0045,.014])

plt.scatter(x,y,color='orange')

spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y)
plt.plot(xs, spl(xs), 'b', lw=3)
plt.show()
```

And what I want to do is find the equation of a line, `y = mx + b`, with a certain y-intercept `a` that hits the blue curve at some tangent point. So, for example, if my line has to pass through `y=.006`, what is the slope `b` of its line that makes it hit the blue line's tangent?

I though about doing a regular optimization over the derivatives of the curve at a large amount of points, but I am unsure how to set this up in a rigorous way.

Comment: What is the equation of the orange line? How did you plot the orange curve?

Comment: Show us some code and effort please.

Comment: I got it from running a portfolio optimization on a bunch of assets, but that is a ton of code I didn't want to post and it didn't seem relevant.

Comment: The tangent will be the smallest slope with all points being below.